# Could not span process for application. The operating system group does not exist

Tags: passenger

Passenger standalone is unable to start my Rails 5.1 application and I am not sure what is going on. It attempts to start the process using my assigned group id (LDAP), which for some reason does not exist in /etc/group:

```
The operating system group '212373379' does not exist
 in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePrepare::resolveUserAndGroup()' (Prepare.h:89)
 in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePrepare::execute()' (Prepare.h:537)
 in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::internalStartPreloader(Passenger::SpawningKit::Config &, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession &, const Json::Value &)' (SmartSpawner.h:340)
 in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:305)
 in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions &)' (SmartSpawner.h:1220)
 in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawningKit::SpawnerPtr &, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options &, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

id displays:

```
uid=864809261(my_account) gid=212373379 groups=212373379,12(everyone),62(netaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin) ...
```

Is there a way for me to pick a different group for passenger to run?

Answer (score -1):

nginx: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_group

or

apache: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengergroup

(...answers need 30 characters to submit...)

Comment: You should provide at least a summary of the pages you are linking to.